# DbContext API Ignore for each entity

Tags: api, entity-framework, dbcontext

I’m trying to use CodeFirst EF. The issue is it's loading 50+ tables for each domain context (DbContext). The ignore is working if I pass the strong name class so the compiler knows what it is but it will be too hard to hardcode all the ignores.

Is there a way to loop through all the classes in a referenced DLL and pass that to the ignore? I have code that is close (taking code from post) but I can’t figure out a way to pass the class type with Assembly information. I’m so close yet so far away…

```
Assembly pocoQMAssembly = AssemblyInformationPOCO_QM.Get;
foreach (Type typeInfo in pocoQMAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    //Make sure it is not one of the classes used in DbSet<> 
    if (typeInfo != typeof(tbl_age_groups) ||
        typeInfo != typeof(tbl_axis)

        )
    { 
        //This line will show an error on typeInfo
        //Is there a way to cast it to a class in some way so it likes it?
        modelBuilder.Ignore<typeInfo>();
    }
}
```

This will expose the Assembly to get it easily.

```
public class AssemblyInformationPOCO_QM
{

    public static System.Reflection.Assembly Get
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(AssemblyInformationPOCO_QM).Assembly;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to Ignore? The DbSets don't load any data.

Comment: There are several hundred tables in the database. All of the tables/classes are in a DLL. They have a lot of forien keys so it links to way more tables than are needed. So the DbSet have what is needed (10 tables/classes) but 60-80 are mapped. So I want to ignore all the other tables except the ones in the DbSet<>. It is easier to check for the ones in the DbSet<> and do nothing then remove the reset than it is to try to remove the ones not needed. The remove lines would be 50-100+ in each domain context.

Comment: OK, I never used Ignore. What happens if you ignore a class that is linked to in a foreign key but has no DbSet?

Comment: OK, I never used Ignore. What happens if you ignore a class that is linked to in a foreign key but has no DbSet? -- In that case the related table that is mapped is not loaded in the metadata. If it is needed later in a Linq query an .Include can be used and it will load the data.

Comment: Ah right. Well, Ignore has an overload that accepts an IEnumerable of types, could that save you?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that without passing the generic perameter. Do you know of an example somewhere?

Comment: See Rowan Miller's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that does what you are after. It finds all types that are explicitly included in a DbSet property, it then uses this to find all types in your model assembly that aren't in a DbSet, and then calls Ignore on them.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{

    // DbSet properties go here

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var dbSetTypes = this.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name == "DbSet`1")
            .Select(s => s.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Single());

        var nonDbSetTypes = typeof(MyEntityClass).Assembly // <- replace MyEntityClass with one of your types
            .GetTypes()
            .Except(dbSetTypes);

        modelBuilder.Ignore(nonDbSetTypes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm overriding the `IdentityDbContext` and have created a custom `IdentityUserLogin<TKey>` that its key is composed of more properties. Now I want EF to ignore the `UserLogins` property and not create a table and set for it at all. I've tried `builder.Ignore<IdentityUserLogin<TKey>>()` but it doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting an error when trying to add migration `The entity type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a key to be defined` I tried shadowing the `UserLogins` property of the base class but then the error is `Ambiguous match found`

Comment: I've also tried `      builder.Model.RemoveEntityType(builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<TKey>>().Metadata);` with no success.